# How do I iterate across malloc? (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, malloc, iteration

I am using code from [this site](http://anikettatipamula.blogspot.in/2012/02/hand-gesture-using-opencv.html)

However there is a mistake in the code where part of it got deleted.

Here is the relevant section of the code

```
CvConvexityDefect* defectArray;
for (; defects; defects = defects->h_next)
            {
                int nomdef = defects->total; // defect amount
                                             //outlet_float( m_nomdef, nomdef );
                                             //printf(" defect no %d \n",nomdef);
                if (nomdef == 0)
                    continue;
// Alloc memory for defect set.
                //fprintf(stderr,"malloc\n");
                defectArray = (CvConvexityDefect*)malloc(sizeof(CvConvexityDefect)*nomdef);
                // Get defect set.
                //fprintf(stderr,"cvCvtSeqToArray\n");
                cvCvtSeqToArray(defects, defectArray, CV_WHOLE_SEQ);
                // Draw marks for all defects.

               //THIS IS WHERE THE MISTAKE IS
                    for (int i = 0; //THE REST OF THIS LINE IS MISSING
                { printf(" defect depth for defect %d %f \n",i,defectArray[i].depth);
                    cvLine(img_8uc3, *(defectArray[i].start), *(defectArray[i].depth_point),CV_RGB(255,255,0),1, CV_AA, 0);
                    cvCircle(img_8uc3, *(defectArray[i].depth_point), 5, CV_RGB(0,0,164), 2, 8,0);
                    cvCircle(img_8uc3, *(defectArray[i].start), 5, CV_RGB(0,0,164), 2, 8,0);
                    cvLine(img_8uc3, *(defectArray[i].depth_point), *(defectArray[i].end),CV_RGB(255,255,0),1, CV_AA, 0);
                }
```

As you can see, part of the for loop is missing. I cant figure out how to complete the for loop so that it iterates over `defectArray`

How do I do this?

Comment: Um, the loop **doesn't** "iterate over `defectArray`". It iterates over the numbers 0 to <number of things in the array minus 1>. How many things are in the array, and how do you iterate over a range of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nomdef; i++)
```